# Export SQL Azure Database with Certificate and SymmetricKey

Tags: database, azure, encryption

I have a Azure SQL Database with certificate and asymmetric key to encrypt one of columns. I want to see how Export/Import work for a database with an encrypted column; Export fails with this error:
Error encountered during the service operation. 
    Could not extract package from specified database.
        The element SymKey_Password is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

Do you know how I can get backup of databases with Certificate and Asymetric key in Azure?

I am open to other ways to encrypt the column. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking for other options, why dont you try using [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dynamic-data-masking-get-started) feature of Azure SQL.

You can encrypt the column and it will only be visible to privileged user with `UNMASK` privilege.

Comment: I actually thought about that but the problem with data masking is , a developer can guess password. You just need to use LIKE statement and find out all characters.